# Issue with QLayout with QStackedWidget

Tags: c++, qt, layout

I am implementing a tab style UI. where tabs are shown by QListWidget and contents are shown by QStackedWidget. on every page of QStackWidget there is layout which allow to insert panel(widget) in QHBoxlayout. at every panel, there are couple of icons which are again in QHBoxLayout. Below is ideal case which I wanted to implement.

[image]

But on other page of QStackWidget this is not the case (with less icons) as below

[image]

I want to remove extra space ( or align icon to left to eliminate extra space among icons on panels)

I tried spacer, then this happened :(

[image]

please help me to correct this thing. My spacer code is as

```
 inline QSpacerItem * buildSpacer(Qt::Orientation orientation)
 {
        QSpacerItem * pSpacer = nullptr;
        if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal)
        {
            pSpacer = new QSpacerItem(1000, UNIT_VALUE, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Minimum);
        }
        else
        {
            pSpacer = new QSpacerItem(UNIT_VALUE, 1000, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
        }
        return pSpacer;
 }
```

**Note**
I donot want to use QTabWidget. By the way this issue is also with QTabWidget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using [QTabWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html) in the first place?

Anyway, instead of creating the QSpacerItem by yourself, you should use [addStretch()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addStretch):

```
my_layout->addWidget(new Widget("widget1"));
my_layout->addWidget(new Widget("widget2"));

my_layout->addStretch(1); // will "eat" extra space
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. If it is possible, can you explain what was the mistake with my spacer approach ?

Comment: Hard to say because, as stated in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspaceritem.html#details), "Normally, you don't need to use this class directly". So I never used it :p But looking in Qt's [source code](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/kernel/qboxlayout.cpp#n895), it looks like `insertStretch` (which is called by `addStretch`) uses a code similar to yours, except the spacer is constructed with a null size (0, 0). A stretch value is still used with the spacer, so maybe it just can't be used alone